# Relation between $g(\mathbb{E}[X])$ and $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$ when $g(X)=\frac{X}{1-X}$ is the "odds" function

Tags: probability, expected-value, jensen-inequality

**Some context**: Let's say we draw from an urn containing red and blue balls. We start at $n=1$, draw 1 ball, look at the color, and put it back, and repeat the process at $n=2$, $n=3$, etc., and every time we encounter a red ball we increment a counter $r$. Thus, the counter $b$ of blue balls is simply $b=n-r$. With every observation, we have a new estimate $X(n,r)$ of some other probability. In other words, $X$ is a function of $n$ and $r$ which returns a real number in $[0,1]$. As such, $X$ is the expression of a probability, but it can also be expressed as the odds ratio $\frac{X}{1-X}$.

**Question**: Although both points of view for this probability are equivalent, the expectation of this probability for $n$ is different in both cases. This is because $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]\neq g(\mathbb{E}[X])$ in general. I believe that Jensen's inequality is at play here and yields $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{1-X}\right]>\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{1-\mathbb{E}[X]}$ because the odds transfomation is convex, and I am wondering if there is any way to use a "convexity correction" of some sort to go from one expectation to the other?

**Expression:** Going back to the urn example, suppose the probability of drawing a red ball is $p$, the probability mass function is binomial and we can express both expectations as (I think):
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X(n,r)\right]=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}X(n,r)\\
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X(n,r)}{1-X(n,r)}\right]=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}\frac{X(n,r)}{1-X(n,r)}
$$
Is there any way to go from, say, the expectation of the odds $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{1-X}\right]$ to the expectation of the probability $\mathbb{E}[X]$?

The only thing I have found so far are [pages 2 and 3 of this appendix](https://cdn-links.lww.com/permalink/ede/b/ede_2022_03_25_sadatsafavi_ede21-0752_sdc1.pdf), but it basically states the same problem I am encountering without proposing a way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're trying to estimate the fraction $p$ of red balls in the urn.  Thus after $n$ drawings with $r$ red balls your estimator is $r/n$.  I'll write that as $X = R/n$ where $R$ is a random variable with binomial distribution having parameters $n$ and $p$.  We have $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[R]/n = p$.  On the other hand,
$\mathbb E[X/(1-X)]$ does not exist because there is a nonzero probability of $X=1$ (i.e. all balls drawn were red), leading to a division by $0$.

EDIT: If $Y = X/(1-X)$ then $X = Y/(1+Y)$.  Assuming $|Y| < 1$ with probability $1$ (i.e. $X < 1/2$), we can expand this in a convergent series
$X = Y - Y^2 + Y^3 - Y^4 + \ldots$, so
$$\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[Y] - \mathbb E[Y^2] + \mathbb E[Y^3] - \mathbb E[Y^4] + \ldots$$
But in any case you need more information than just $\mathbb E[Y]$.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to estimate the number of red balls. The probability X(n,r) is a function of those observations but is a different probabiliy. If we were to look at log-odds (a logit), they would go to $-\infty$ as X goes to 0 and $+\infty$ as X goes to 1. I am trying to estimate E[X] from E[odds] and vice versa.

Comment: I am looking at your edit (which I was lucky to see), and this could be more promising. In my specific case, calculating E[X] is an intensive computation while E[Y] is not. Your expansion is similar to the idea proposed by @Golden_Ratio, but in this case I could perhaps correct the convexity this way to an arbitrary level of precision. I must now check if $E[Y^2]$, $E[Y^3]$, etc. is calculatable easily in my case but I believe it is! Will keep you posted.

Comment: I tried several things but I am not able to work with this method so far. As X is between 0 and 1, the odds go from 0 to 1 when X<1/2, and the expansion you provide around Y=0 works well. But for X>1/2, I have tried the expansion at Y=1 and that does not look pretty even for fairly low values of Y. The expansion at $Y=\infty$ is a very good approximation for those values, unfortunately 1/Y is degenerate in my case. Therefore, I was wondering if working with logs would help since it would make both situations X<1/2 and X>1/2 symmetrical? Unfortunately the expansion around 1 is no better...

Comment: I have finally been able to confirm that this works and is the correct answer (I also give credit and thanks to @Golden_Ratio for being the first to mention the expansion, though in a way that was less straightforward for me, the real "click" being this answer). That being said, this is not a magic bullet, and I have had trouble making this work numerically (this is why it tooks a while to accept this answe): odds can quickly increase if X>1/2, and the expectation means that we are trying to expand at a point which could be very far from the various values of Y present in the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

$E\left[{X \over 1-X}\right]$ bakes in higher order moment information than just $E[X]$.  In particular, assuming $|X|<1$ with probability $1$, then

$$E\left[{X \over 1-X}\right]=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^\infty X^i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty E\left[X^i\right].$$

Comment: Thanks! Using the expansion is an interesting avenue, though I am not too sure how to use this knowledge to go from E[odds} to E[X]? Is there a specific reference by any chance?

Comment: @sg1234 I don't see how you can back out $E[X]$ from $E[\text{odds}]$ in general.  For instance, suppose $X$ is almost surely $1$.  Then $E[\text{odds}]$ doesn't offer much to work with.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "E[odds] does not offer much to work with"? I can imagine both expressions can be mapped as going from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ (e.g. using log for E[odds] and arctanh over a linear transformation of E[X]). Would such a mapping help give "more to work with"?